# What is the Bound Flipping Ratio test?

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

The bound flipping ratio test (BFRT) appears to be an [important feature](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/484/simplex-implementations-in-professional-solvers/490#490) of modern Simplex implementations.

What is it, and how does it work?

Comment: I assume that the answers in google "bound flipping ratio test koberstein" don't satisfy you?

Comment: The Koberstein paper is what I will be summing up in my own answer later, if noone else takes the opportunity first.

Comment: ah, OK, you are still in beta mode...

Comment: Does it really matter if it stays in beta? https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ has been in beta for over 7 1/2 years and I think is doing just fine..People there aren't posting questions just for the sake of posting questions, or artificially breaking up questions into a bunch of little pieces just to have more questions. If the OR site "wins" by being promoted out of beta, is that a real victory if it comes at the cost of clutter and questions for the sake of questions?

Answer (score 5):

When taking a step in the dual simplex method, if a dual variable is zeroed, the dual objective may continue to improve if the variable passes through zero. To maintain dual feasibility, the variable must be associated with a primal variable with finite lower and upper bounds. As the dual variable passes through zero, the corresponding primal variable [which is necessarily nonbasic] "flips" from one bound to the other. This process changes the gradient of the dual objective, making it less attractive to make a further change in the dual variable. Thus, eventually, the ratio test will terminate (unless the LP is dual unbounded).